# LVM Ontop of LUKS using Grub

Tags: arch-linux, grub, luks, lvm

## What am I trying to do?

Install Arch with full system encryption (sans boot and media partition) using LVM on top of LUKS on an external hard drive (sdb)
using: http://suddenkernelpanic.blogspot.com/2013/03/arch-linux-lvm-on-top-of-luks-2013-style.html

## What is my problem:

System boots grub and it appears there is some confusion on where to find root

> Error: Device 'uuid=f7153c4b-e6ea-48a2-9ee1-bf38c037173d' not found. skipping fsck
>
> Error: Unable to find root device 'uuid=f7153c4b-e6ea-48a2-9ee1-bf38c037173d'

Where I deviated from this tutorial

1. I used Grub Instead of Syslinux as the tutorial suggests (This seems to be the crux) and it's really hazy on the solution for Grub
2. My partition scheme consists of an extra FAT32 partition that is not involved in the encryption (seems irrelevant to the issue)

## Issues on /etc/default/grub:

(I feel like this is where the issue is)

From what I've read I need to update a couple of places in this file specifically:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="root=/dev/mapper/lvmpool-root cryptdevice=/dev/sdb2:crypt ro"
```

and I'm supposed to uncomment:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
```

## Issues on `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`

I'm supposed to add the hooks as follows

```
HOOKS="... encrypt lvm2 ... filesystems ..."
```

## Here's my fstab entry for root

```
<filesystem>
/dev/mapper/lvmpool-root                                                 
UUID=f7153c4b-e6ea-48a2-9ee1-bf38c037173d / ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered   0 1
```

## Current Work-Around

I can still use the system because after it errors out, it drops me into a recovery shell, at which type I can simply do a:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 crypt 
enter password
```

Then exit recovery shell and it drops me back into a normal arch login prompt.
This wouldn't be so bad, if it weren't so time consuming... (Takes forever to error out on boot, like 20 seconds)

Other Resources I tried

I have also used:

- wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide
- wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gr … encryption
- wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm … oot_loader
- wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm … VM_on_LUKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in the difference of `:crypt` as volume group for `/dev/sdb2` and using `lvmpool-` as volumegroup name as parameter for root.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="root=/dev/mapper/lvmpool-root cryptdevice=/dev/sdb2:crypt ro"
```

The example [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Configuring_the_boot_loader_2):

```
cryptdevice=/dev/partition:MyStorage root=/dev/mapper/MyStorage-rootvol
```

has matching `:MyStorage` and `MyStorage-`. That [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system) specifically targets `grub` (and not Syslinux), with LVM on top of LUKS. So I would follow that set up.

That you have an extra, not encrypted partition, doesn't matter.

Comment: This is what keeps getting me.
When they state things like "partition" do they mean SDB2 or SDB and does "Mystorage" mean LVMpool or Crypt or what? Those words are just so friggin' vague

Comment: In "Preparing the logical volumes" it says that MyStorage is the Volume Group and rootvol the Logical Volume

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Anthon for your answer above, it greatly contributed to solving my problem.

It seems the solution to my issue was two parts.

1. The entry in /etc/default/grub, for me should read:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/sdb2:lvmpool root=/dev/mapper/lvmpool-root"
>   
>   To break down each entry:

cryptdevice consists of the partition you applied the encryption too, in my case /dev/sdb2 and lvmpool (my volume group)

root is simply pointing to the location of my encrypted root lvmpool (which is located on sdb2)

2. After that entry is made (and this was a key mistake for me) you must run:

> grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
>   
>   This will update your /boot/grub/grub.cfg with the information you added to /etc/default/grub.

After I did that, the system booted straight into the prompt to unlock the root partition.

Answer (score 0):

include in `mkinitcpio.conf`

```
MODULES="dm_mod dm_crypt ext4 aes_x86_64 sha256 sha512"

HOOKS="... encrypt lvm2 ..."
```

---

include in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... quiet "

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/sdX:name"

GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK="y"
```

---

run command:

```
sudo mkinitcpio -p linux

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

sudo grub-install --recheck --target=i386-pc /dev/sda

sudo pacman -S linux linux-headers
```